# Устаревшая строка DOCTYPE

Tags: html5

Объясните зачем использовать данную строку ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Объясните зачем использовать данную строку <!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">?

Comment: @Anton это используется если ты вынужден использовать что-то похожее на HTML4/XHTML, нашёл по первому запросу, постарайтесь сначала сами искать... [`<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33575986)